# Connecting range selector on two graphs

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs

I am trying to build a shiny application where two Dygraph visuals are controlled with a single range selector. I'm not exactly sure where to start and am assuming this is something that can't be done out of the box. Would it require another package to control both sliders with?

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)



shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Education"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      br("test")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dygraphOutput("dygraph1"),
      dygraphOutput("dygraph2")
    )
  )
))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)



df_education <-  
read.csv("C:/Users/adarvishian/Documents/rworking/dygraphtest/education.csv")



education_subset <- df[c(12:55),c(3,8:11)]

w1 = 0.25
w2 = 0.25
w3 = 0.25
w4 = 0.25

education_subset$Index = w1*education_subset$Secondary.school.enrollment+w2*education_subset$Primary.school.enrollment+w3*education_subset$Preprimary.school.enrollment+w4*education_subset$Tertiary.school.enrollment


index_edu<- education_subset[,c(1,6)]



function(input, output){

  output$dygraph1 <- renderDygraph({
   dygraph(education_subset, main = "Education Components") %>%
      dyRangeSelector()

  })

  output$dygraph2 <- renderDygraph({
    dygraph(index_edu, main = "Education Index") %>%
      dyRangeSelector()
    })


}
```

**data**

https://github.com/adarvishian/dygraphtest.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by xo_gene, below is the code for same:

```
library(dygraphs)
library(datasets)



ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

    mainPanel(
      dygraphOutput("dygraph"),dygraphOutput("dygraph1"),dygraphOutput("dygraph2")
    )
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  output$dygraph <- renderDygraph({
    dygraph(ldeaths, main = "All", group = "lung-deaths")
  })
  output$dygraph1 <- renderDygraph({
    dygraph(mdeaths, main = "Male", group = "lung-deaths")
  })
  output$dygraph2 <- renderDygraph({
    dygraph(fdeaths, main = "Female", group = "lung-deaths")
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This was the key! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the [synchronization](https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-synchronization.html) feature of the dygraphs library would get you where you're trying to go?

Comment: Yes, this worked! Thank you. Didn't realize that's what the group feature could be used for.